# Count multiple columns database and update the counter to another columns (in another row)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and have this table called ads_sponsers:

[image]

As you can see, there are many ads in this table, each ad has its id (the ad number 4 is on id =4).

The number of ads that will be shown to the user is 3 random ads from table (ads_sponsers).

So when the ads are shown to the client, it's updated into another table called ads_sponsers_log and this table looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, from this second table (ads_sponsers_log) the ad with **id =1** is shown **6 times**, the ad with **id = 2** is shown **6 times**, the ad with **id = 5** is shown **2 times** and so on.

I want to count the ad with the `id = $id` into table ads_sponsers to show how many times the ad is shown to the users.

I tried like this (before I created the new table ads_sponsers_log):

```
$ads_info = $this->basic->get_data('ads_sponser',$where,$select);
foreach ($ads_info as $count) {
$count_ads = 0;
$ads_column_id = $count['id'];
$count_ads = $count['count_ads'];
$count_ads++;  
$update_ads = array("count_ads" =>$count_ads);
$this->basic->update_data("ads_sponsers",array("id"=>$ads_column_id),$update_ads);
    
}
```

And all the `row->conter_ads` from all id's are updated with +1.

Also I tried now like this:

```
$ads_info = $this->basic->get_data('ads_sponser',$where,$select);
                    
shuffle($ads_info); 
$count_ads1 = 0;
$ads1 = $ads_info[0]['id'] ;
$count_ads1 = $ads_info[0]['count_ads'];
$count_ads1++; 
$update_ads1 = array("count_ads" =>$count_ads1);
$this->basic->update_data("ads_sponser",array("id"=>$ads1),$update_ads1);
$count_ads2 = 0;
$ads2 = $ads_info[1]['id'];
$count_ads2 = $ads_info[1]['count_ads'];
$count_ads2++; 
$update_ads2 = array("count_ads" =>$count_ads2);
$this->basic->update_data("ads_sponser",array("id"=>$ads2),$update_ads2);
$count_ads3 = 0;
$ads3 = $ads_info[2]['id'];
$count_ads3 = $ads_info[2]['count_ads'];
$count_ads3++; 
$update_ads3 = array("count_ads" =>$count_ads3);
$this->basic->update_data("ads_sponser",array("id"=>$ads3),$update_ads3);
```

But I am afraid that it will affect the server load due to many SQL queries in one operation.

Can you please help me with this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a `WHERE IN` clause to update the `ads_sponsers` table with one query for each set of 3 ads being shown. The `ads_sponsers_log` table is then no longer necessary.

Get the `id`s of the 3 ads you want to show:

```
$ads_info = $this->basic->get_data('ads_sponser',$where,$select);
                    
shuffle($ads_info); 
$ads1 = $ads_info[0]['id'] ;
$ads2 = $ads_info[1]['id'];
$ads3 = $ads_info[2]['id'];
```

And then increase `count_ads` by 1 for these `id`s only:

```
$this->db->set('count_ads', 'count_ads + 1', FALSE);
$this->db->where_in('id', [$ads1, $ads2, $ads3]);
$this->db->update('ads_sponsers');
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m6jRLCkH5djd5BF16daDpR/0 (Click "Run" in the top bar to view the results - after the `UPDATE` query, the value in the `count_ads` column for `id`s 1, 3 and 5 has increased by one).